# Package guile-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: graphics, fedora

I was installing libgraph in fedora.
I did install these and they were installed

But still im not able to install libgraph.The same code i run on the pc in my college, libgraph was installed.

```
[root@localhost libgraph-1.0.2]# yum install SDL.x86_64 SDL-devel.x86_64 SDL_image.x86_64 SDL_image-devel.x86_64
Redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf install SDL.x86_64 SDL-devel.x86_64 SDL_image.x86_64 SDL_image-devel.x86_64' (see 'man yum2dnf')
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:24 ago on Wed Jan 18 16:40:27 2017.
Package SDL-1.2.15-21.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Package SDL-devel-1.2.15-21.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Package SDL_image-1.2.12-14.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Package SDL_image-devel-1.2.12-14.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

[root@localhost libgraph-1.0.2]# dnf install Guile guile.x86_64 guile.i686 guile-devel.x86_64 compat-guile18-devel.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 0:25:13 ago on Wed Jan 18 16:40:27 2017.
No package Guile available.
Package guile-5:2.0.13-1.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Package guile-5:2.0.13-1.fc24.i686 is already installed, skipping.
Package compat-guile18-devel-1.8.8-13.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

but still if i type ./configure i get this error

```
         [root@localhost libgraph-1.0.2]# ./configure
 checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
 checking whether build environment is sane... yes
 checking for gawk... gawk
 checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
 checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
 checking for gcc... gcc
 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
 checking for suffix of executables... 
 checking for suffix of object files... o
 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
 checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
 checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
 checking for style of include used by make... GNU
 checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
 checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
 checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
 checking whether ln -s works... yes
 checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
 checking for egrep... grep -E
 checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
 checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
 checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
 checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
 checking for sys/types.h... yes
 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
 checking for stdlib.h... yes
 checking for string.h... yes
 checking for memory.h... yes
 checking for strings.h... yes
 checking for inttypes.h... yes
 checking for stdint.h... yes
 checking for unistd.h... yes
 checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
 checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
 checking for dlfcn.h... yes
 checking for g++... g++
 checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
 checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
 checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
 checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
 checking for g77... no
 checking for f77... no
 checking for xlf... no
 checking for frt... no
 checking for pgf77... no
 checking for fort77... no
 checking for fl32... no
 checking for af77... no
 checking for f90... no
 checking for xlf90... no
 checking for pgf90... no
 checking for epcf90... no
 checking for f95... no
 checking for fort... no
 checking for xlf95... no
 checking for ifc... no
 checking for efc... no
 checking for pgf95... no
 checking for lf95... no
 checking for gfortran... no
 checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
 checking whether  accepts -g... no
 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
 checking for objdir... .libs
 checking for ar... ar
 checking for ranlib... ranlib
 checking for strip... strip
 checking if gcc static flag  works... yes
 checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
 checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
 checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
 checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
 checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
 checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
 checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
 checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
 checking whether to build static libraries... yes
 configure: creating libtool
 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
 checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
 checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
 checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
 checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
 checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
 checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
 appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
 checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
 checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
 checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.0... yes
 checking SDL  ==>  SDL_image library... SDL_image = yes
 checking for Guile... Package guile-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
 Perhaps you should add the directory containing `guile-2.0.pc'
 to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
 No package 'guile-2.0' found
 error: ("pkg-config" "--libs" "guile-2.0") exited with non-zero error code 1
 configure: cannot find guile-config; is Guile installed?
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

dnf install guile guile.x86_64 guile.i686 guile-devel.x86_64 compat-guile18-devel.x86_64